# firebase user is returning null everytime after it is called for the firsttime

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

Firebase user is returning null after this `(user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();)` is called for the first time.

when the app is installed for the first time the `firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()` is returning the users but when it is moving from the first activity to another activity and the sigh Out button is called after that `firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()` is returning null every time.

```
package com.example.firebaselogin;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;

public class logIn extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText userName, pwd;
    TextView signUpHere;
    Button loginButton;
    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    //private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener listener;

    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    FirebaseUser user;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_log_in);

        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

        user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

        userName = findViewById(R.id.userName);
        pwd = findViewById(R.id.pwd);
        signUpHere = findViewById(R.id.signUpHere);
        loginButton = findViewById(R.id.loginButton);

        loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                progressDialog.setMessage("Please Wait");
                progressDialog.show();

                Log.i("Userrrr", String.valueOf(user));

                if(validate()) {
                    if (user != null) {
                        firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(userName.getText().toString().trim(), pwd.getText().toString().trim()).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(logIn.this, WelcomePage.class);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                                } else {
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        signUpHere.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }

    private Boolean validate() {

        Boolean result = false;

        String name = userName.getText().toString();
        String password = pwd.getText().toString();

        if(name.isEmpty() || password.isEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter all details", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            result = true;
        }

        return result;

    }

}
```

When the `firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()` is called for the fisrt time, it is

> returning (2019-08-29 00:08:14.561 8165-8165/com.example.firebaselogin
>   I/Userrrr: com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzk@44ffb65)  but after
>   the signOut is triggered from a next activity,
>   firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() is returning null everytime 2019-08-29
>   00:08:24.651 8165-8165/com.example.firebaselogin I/Userrrr: null``

Comment: when signout is called, it logs out the user session .So there will be no user and it returns null obviously

Comment: but after coming to the login Activity it can't get signed in again. How to get the user after signout is calld?

Comment: just removed if(user != null) {} line...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can see, you are checking whether user is null or not before signing the user. So when the user logs out and when he tries to login again, now the user is null. According to your condition, if the user is not null, it will all to sign in, other it wont. As the user is null, it always fails and user cant login. Remove that condition and you are good to go.

Comment: yes..now my question is how I will get back to login after a signOut?

Comment: Ok.Tell me what activities you are having and the series of activies.I will help you and provide the code for signout button

Comment: I found my mistake now it fixed and thank you so much @Thrishool MSM

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you sign out the user and calls the code

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
```

it will clear the session maintained by firebase. But if `signOut()` is not called then the session will still be there and the user will not be null. So whenever you call `signOut()`, you will get user `null`. So by just removing the `user != null` condition you will be able to sign-in.